# Should i change from erb to haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i first started learning Rails, erb seemed very natural for me, because i've been using Smarty and other templates in the past, and even more, i've been heavily doing some wordpress template programming(where the whole thing looks like erb a lot).

Now, after some time, i happened to take a look at haml and by the first view, i feel quite impressed on the beauty and simplicity. I heard that, especially for older versions, haml is slower, but i feel that view rendering would not really be a problem.

So now, i'm seriously thinking of converting a quite big project that i do, from erb to haml. I'm always looking for ways to write better code.

But, what do you think ? Is it a good idea ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Haml is a great choice for starting a new project. But I don't see the value in converting an existing project from ERB to Haml, especially if you have a large number of templates that need rewriting. Don't fix what ain't broken.

Comment: My main problem is that i feel that erb is quite ugly and i suppose that it can make it hard for me to adjust the views when things become even bigger. I'm really not sure though, but i value your opinion, thanx !

Comment: I really dislike the "Don't fix what ain't broken" line. I refactor ugly code continually to make it better. So why not the views as well? I think it really makes sense to refactor before things really break. To keep it maintainable.

Comment: Maybe what you need is to use more helpers if the code in your views is ugly.

Comment: @nathvanda: Point taken. But there is always the question of how to spend one's limited resources. Refactoring purely for the sake of making ugly code pretty doesn't seem like a good use of time. ERB works well and won't break -- while Haml is a great aid to productivity, it doesn't make your code more robust.

Answer (score 3):

I agree there is no real need to migrate, you can simply mix and match them.

But ... I do strongly advice you to effectively switch to haml. I feel the effort in converting erb to haml is not that big. Most of the times you will be cutting out elements. The reward on the other hand is great.

Haml is much more compact, and most importantly: more readable.
Because it is very structured, the nesting is much clearer and it makes your views much more maintainable.

I don't know about yours, but we had erb-templates that were totally unreadable, different developers have different styles, how do you handle nesting inside erb? nested code? nested code inside elements? nested elements inside code?
In haml there is no question about that. It is clear. Everything is indented as you nest. And no need to un-nest, no more forgetting a closing `</td>` or `</div>`.

Also it makes your files much smaller (easier to overlook).

There is indeed a possible performance issue, but if that really is a concern of you, i would suggest looking at [slim](https://github.com/stonean/slim), which is nearly identical to haml, only blindingly fast.

Answer (score 1):

Haml is great, and I recommend it for future templates. However, you have no need to change your existing erb code to haml, since you can freely mix erb and haml in a project. As views get unwieldy, you could consider rewrites, but there's no real need to change them all over at once - that would take quite a while, and potentially introduce bugs.